# How to Filter data with R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a database consisting of

- Code of middle schools (code)
- Gender of the students ; 1:Male,2:Female (Cod_Sexe)
- Decision Concerning the student; A: Pass , R:Fail (Decision)
- Behaviour of the student during the year ; 0: Bad , 1:Good (Conduite).

This data is divided over 3 years: 2008,2011 and 2014.
I am using R shiny, I created graphs for gender, decision and behaviour and just display the number of middle schools and students. Now I want to enable the user to filter this data according to a certain year.
Here's the code:

**USER INTERFACE**

```
 ui <- fluidPage( 
    textOutput("inst_nbr"),
    textOutput("stunbr"),
    plotOutput("plot_decision"),
    plotOutput("genderdonut"),
    plotOutput("Conduite"),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "YearSelect", "Select the corresponding year", 
      choices = levels(factor(Test2008$Year)), selected = levels(factor(Test2008$Year)))
)
```

> inst_nbr : middle school number / stunbr: students number / plot_decision: histogram of the decisions(A/R) / genderdonut:donut chart for the gender distribution / Conduite:donut chart for the behavior / YearSelect: filter created from the database

**Server**

```
# CREATE YEAR FILTER
    TestFilter <- reactive({ # <-- Reactive function here
        Test2008 %>% 
            filter(Test2008$Year == input$YearSelect)
    })

# NBR OF INSTITUTIONS
    output$inst_nbr=  renderText({
        Test=TestFilter()
        length(unique(x = Test$Code))
        })

# PLOT DECISION DIAGRAM
    # % of each decison
    Per_A= 100*length(which(Test2008$Decision=='A'))/length(Test2008$Decision)
    Per_R= 100*length(which(Test2008$Decision=='R'))/length(Test2008$Decision)
    DecisionName=c('Accepté','Refusé')
    DecisionFraction=c(Per_A,Per_R)
    # Plot of decisions
    output$plot_decision=renderPlot({
        Test=TestFilter()
        barplot(height= DecisionFraction, names = DecisionName )
    })
```

I applied the filter to the number of middle school, it works when I check each year alone, however when I check all the boxes it doesn't return the total. I don't know how to apply it to the graph on the other hand.
In addition when I run the application I get these errors:

> Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
> x Input `..1` must be of size 111613 or 1, not size 0.
> i Input `..1` is `Test2008$Year == input$YearSelect`.
> 170:  (Occurs when no box is checked)

And

> Warning in Test2008$Year == input$YearSelect :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

**DUMMY DATA**

```
Code     Cod_sexe    conduite   decision    year 
1002        1           1           A       2008
2065        1           0           R       2008
1002        2           1           A       2008
4225        2           1           R       2011        
2005        1           1           R       2011
1003        2           0           R       2014
2005        2           0           A       2014
```

Comment: For the 2 warnings I got a solution. In the filter instead of writing              
    ' filter(Test2008$Year == input$YearSelect) '                                                                           
 I need to write ' filter(Test2008$Year %in%  input$YearSelect) '                                                  However, I still don't know how to filter my graphs

Comment: Please provide us with some dummy data to make your example reproducible.

Comment: Next time please use the output of `dput(Test2008)` or `head(dput(Test2008), 7)` and copy it here. This makes it much easier to work with your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your plot reactive, you need to use your reactive dataset `TestFilter` rather than your static data.frame `Test2008` to create the plot.

I'm nnot sure if this is the logic you want, but it should get you started.

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

Test2008 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Code = c(1002L, 2065L, 1002L, 4225L, 2005L, 1003L, 2005L),
  Cod_sexe = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
  conduite = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  Decision = c("A", "R", "A", "R", "R", "R", "A"),
  Year = c(2008L, 2008L, 2018L, 2011L, 2011L, 2014L, 2014L)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = "YearSelect",
    "Select the corresponding year",
    choices = unique(Test2008$Year),
    selected = unique(Test2008$Year)
  ),
  textOutput("inst_nbr"),
  textOutput("stunbr"),
  plotOutput("plot_decision"),
  plotOutput("genderdonut"),
  plotOutput("Conduite")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # CREATE YEAR FILTER
  TestFilter <- reactive({
    Test2008 %>% filter(Year %in% input$YearSelect)
  })
  
  # NBR OF INSTITUTIONS
  output$inst_nbr = renderText({
    length(unique(TestFilter()$Code))
  })
  
  # PLOT DECISION DIAGRAM
  output$plot_decision = renderPlot({
    req(TestFilter())
    # % of each decison
    Per_A = 100 * length(which(TestFilter()$Decision == 'A')) / length(TestFilter()$Decision)
    Per_R = 100 * length(which(TestFilter()$Decision == 'R')) / length(TestFilter()$Decision)
    DecisionName = c('Accepté', 'Refusé')
    DecisionFraction = c(Per_A, Per_R)
    barplot(height = DecisionFraction, names = DecisionName)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]